# Node async.waterfall passing of variables between modules

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module

I have problem passing variables between modules when using async.waterfall. This is my main runner.

```
var async = require('async');
var helpers = require('./1-helpers');

var file = process.argv[2];
var body = '';

async.waterfall([helpers.getURL, helpers.openURL, helpers.printBody]);
```

and functions are all in this file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

module.exports = {

  getURL: function (done) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', this.gotFileData);
  },

  gotFileData: function (err, url) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(null, url);
  },

  openURL: function (url, done) {   
    http.get(url, this.handleResponse).on('error', function (e) {
      done(e);
    });
  },

  handleResponse: function (res) {
    res.on('data', this.readChunk);
    res.on('end', function gotBody (chunk) {
      done(null, body);
    });
  },

  readChunk: function (chunk) {
    body += chunk.toString();
  },

  printBody: function (err, body) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(body);
  }

}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
/Users/wimo/dev/nodejs/async-you/1-helpers.js:7
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', this.gotFileData);
            ^

ReferenceError: file is not defined
    at getURL (/Users/wimo/dev/nodejs/async-you/1-helpers.js:7:17)
    at nextTask (/Users/wimo/dev/nodejs/async-you/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5021:18)
    at Object.waterfall (/Users/wimo/dev/nodejs/async-you/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5024:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wimo/dev/nodejs/async-you/1.js:7:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
```

Any tips on passing the 'file' and 'body' variables through the async.waterfall functions please?

Many thanks,
Wim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main.js

Pass first function async.constant in async.waterfall this will pass the variable file as argument to getURL function. Refer to [Documentation of async.constant](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.constant) and [How to pass argument to first waterfall function](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/14)

```
async.waterfall([async.constant(file), helpers.getURL, helpers.openURL, helpers.printBody], function(err) 
{ console.log(err); });
```

In helper.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
module.exports = {
 getURL: function (file, callback) {
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, fileData) {
   if (err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
   }
   callback(null, fileData);
  });
 },
 openURL: function (url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function (err, httpResponse) {
   if (err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
   }
  callback(null, httpResponse);
  });
 },
 printBody: function (httpResponse, callback) {
  httpResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
  console.log(chunk);
  callback(null, 'done');
 });
 }
}
```

Async.js uses the callback to determine if an error has occurred or not and arguments to the callback are passed to the next task.
Here, fileData, result of fs.readile function is passed to getURL (next task). Therefore, url gets the value of fileData. [async.waterfall documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall)

Comment: Great, thanks Himani! I used async.apply instead and it works well passing "file" var.